# Returning an object which will only be used sometimes

Tags: python, selenium, pageobjects

**Python - Page Object Model**

Does returning a page object which will only be used in 80% of cases violate any best practices?

```
def delete_list_item_by_name(self, item_name):
    ... code to find the proper list item ...
    row_del_btn = self.helpers.wait().until(ec.visibility_of(row.find_element(*self.DELETE_BTN)))
    ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(row_del_btn).click(row_del_btn).perform()
    return DeleteConfirmModal(self.driver)
```

The issue is that the `deleteConfirmModal` (a pop up) only pops up **80%** of the time after the delete button is clicked. So there's differing opinions on whether it's page object should be returned.  The page object has no `init` so won't cause a failure.  Returning the page object is more of a convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You actually return a reference to the object, meaning that, if it is not used, it will be garbage collected (deleted from memory).

It causes no significant problems in terms of performance.

In term of best practices, you should name your function appropriately to indicate that it returns something `pop_by_name` would probably be better (`pop` means delete and return).

Comment: I like the idea of pop but we're already committed to following the UI element's mouseover text of edit and delete, depending.